# Adonisjs last update (v5) model create command Not working

Tags: typescript, adonis.js, adonisjs-ace

Adonisjs **v5**

Create a controller command work fine.

```
node ace make:controller Posts
```

But Create a new model Command not working

```
node ace:make model Post
```

Run the make model command show error

**Cannot find module 'C:\Users\abir2\Desktop\crm-backend\ace:make'**

adonisjs v5 How to create a model using command?

Comment: Did you try : `node ace make:model Post`? `ace` is a **file**

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```sh
node ace make:model Posts
```

You can check the help directly on the cmd

```sh
node ace make --help
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you already have lucid [setup](https://docs.adonisjs.com/guides/database/introduction)

Generate ace commands manifest file

```
node ace generate:manifest
```

Check if the command was generated

```
node ace make --help
```

Retry the model command

```
node ace make:model Post
```

Answer (score 1):

According to adonisjs documentation:
Assuming you already have lucid set up, run the following command to create your first data model

```
node ace make:model User
```

let's set up the lucid:

run `npm i @adonisjs/lucid`
then configure it by runing

```
node ace configure @adonisjs/lucid
```

finally run above ace command to create model